# How to get Gradient Color Value in HTML from a Image

Tags: css, photoshop, sketchapp

Can anyone explain how to get gradient color value from the image in terms of HTML

Comment: please elaborate more about your question. What exactly you want. Please mention scenario or code snippet etc

Comment: I have this image: http://prntscr.com/krknez and I want its gradient color value in html how can I get???

Comment: you need to pick color manually and then only you can use in HTML/CSS. Here is snippet for your color. background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #F46E49, #fff);}

Comment: you can install ColorZilla addon/extension in your chrome browser and then you can easily grab any color code from any image in the world.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pick colour from any image. You have to use colour piker tools like photoshop, Gimp, Krita any other browsers extensions are also available.
Right now you have shared an image, In this image two background colours are available first white (#ffffff), Second Orange (#f86c53).
try this code for gradient:- 
background: linear-gradient(to right, #f86c53 0%, #fff 80%);

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the "Eyedropper" tool which you can add to your browser.

[EyeDropper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eye-dropper/hmdcmlfkchdmnmnmheododdhjedfccka?hl=en)

And after adding to the browser, what you need to do is, go the site where you want the color or colors in the image and use this eye dropper to get that colors and add them to your css.

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f77b5f , white);
```

and also you can check for usage of gradients here [Linear gradients](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp)

Answer (score 0):

you need to pick color manually and then only you can use in HTML/CSS.

Here is snippet for your color.

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #F46E49, #fff);
```